# MATLAB: Why is double looping so much slower than squaring?

Tags: matlab, performance, loops, matrix

I wonder why it is faster to square a matrix with the `A2=A^2` command (`A` being a `LxL` matrix) than to just do a double `for` loop and assign the value to a zeroed matrix. 
I have run the following code to check the first case

```
tic
psi2=psi.^2;
T1=toc;
```

and the following for the second

```
psi2=zeros(L,L);
tic 
for i=1:L
    for j=1:L
        psi2(i,j)=psi(i,j)^2;
    end
end
T2=toc;
```

In [this figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGhPC.png) the elapsed time for several matrices sizes (`L`) are shown and the speedup is clear.

I would not be surprised to see that MATLAB has a very efficient implementation of matrix multiplication as it what is it made for, but I can't understand how there's a faster way to do element-wise operations than just looping over it.

Thanks for time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several things that make the vector operation faster than your loop.

First, a loop compiled into C++ code is faster than a script loop which is interpreted / converted and compiled as Java.

Secondly, the C or C++ compiler can use Single Instruction, Multiple Data instructions (SIMD) to do the operation on multiple matrix elements in a single operation.  And then do this in multiple threads.

Finally, it's possible to push the operation to the GPU which can process even more elements simultaneously (hundreds of cores, compared to 4-8 on the CPU).  Your scripted loops cannot do this.

Comment: Thanks  a lot for your answer. I am quite surprised as I even checked that MATLAB is faster than FORTRAN at doing that. I always regarded MATLAB as slow. I know see that there is a lot going on I did not consider.

Answer (score 1):

.^2 take the advantage of doing parallel operation using CPU. For a nested loop (double loop) solution, the entire solution is done in sequence. In addition it also have over head to increment of the loop control variable and condition checking.